# An issue related to handler in android

Tags: android, handler

I am using following code to run a timer.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
int time=0;
Runnable runable = new Runnable() { 

    @Override 
    public void run() { 
            time++;
            Log.d("time", ""+time);
            textview.setText(""+time);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); 

    } 
}; 
handler.postDelayed(runable, 1000);
```

This handler is attached to UI thread. When I navigate away to some other activity and come back to this activity I get two timers, the old one still persists, I can see this in logcat. Why this is happening ? How to get rid of old timers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have two timers, depends on where your code is in the activity. Activity.onStart and Activity.onResume can (not always) both get called when returning to an activity.

When Activity.onPause, or Activity.onStop is called you can call [handler.removeCallbacks(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to remove your timer runnable.

Comment: It's hard to predict when a backgrounded activity gets [destroyed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) by the OS, as that may be why onCreate is getting called again. My recommendation would be to only have the timer run between onResume and onPause, as that is when your textView is visible.

Comment: i doubt if that will help since I am navigating away and coming back to same activity. Is there a way to kill handler ?

Comment: I don't understand. A handler is a pipe that sends/removes Runnables/Messages to a thread. I believe you are referring to killing the task? (As in removing the runnable from the ui thread).

Keep a handle on the submitted runnable and remove it using the handler at onPause or onStop. It's unwise to assume the same instance of an Activity will be there when you come back to it. Activities are designed to be disposable.

Comment: you are correct same instance of the activity will not be there. However, in this particular case the old handler persists and keep submitting the runnable to UI thread message queue. I used the function removeCallbacks() as suggested by you. That works fine except in one case i.e. when user presses HOME key and restarts the app, then also the old timer persists. How to get rid of this ?

Comment: Strange, even the HOME key should call onPause and onStop. 


If you need the timer to persist across all activities, I would launch it at Application.onCreate(). That's guaranteed to to only run once per app instance, regardless of backgrounded or not.

Comment: Probably i was not clear. All my codes are in onCreate(). I can move it in onPause() or onStop() and stop the handler using removeCallbacks(), but problem is both these methods are executed when user receives a call, in which case i do not want to stop the handler. How to identify the call ?